# Scrollbars don't match the real bounds of transformed object

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I tried to rotate an html-element using `transform: rotate(45deg);`. This did work, however the scrollbars don't match the visual bounds of the rotated element.

The context is that I want to create a pdf-viewer application where the user can also rotate the file for better readability. However, it is impossible for him to scroll across the whole file, because the scrollbars aren't long enough.

Take [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdpganp5/) as an example. The scrollbars are too short, so that you can't scroll to every corner.

How can I fix this, so that you can scroll across the whole element?

**A jQuery solution would be fine. I tested this in Chrome v.60**

Comment: Is the user clicking a button to rotate to one set angle, or is it totally custom how much they rotate?

Comment: @cjl750 He can use a `0` to `359` range slider. I set the rotation like so:
`$('#element').css("transform", "rotate(" + $("#slider").val() + "deg)");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the two main problems I see that we need to overcome are:

1. Image is bigger than the container
2. Even if the image wasn't bigger than the container, as soon as it's rotated, it will be bigger because the length between opposite corners is going to be longer than the length of any one side of the image

So the basic approach here is to add an extra `div` inside of `#wrapper` and:

1. Make the image the same size as `#wrapper`
2. Make sure the new `div` is big enough to fit the image even when it's rotated

The trick is to figure out how big the inner wrapper should be. That's when the gold old [Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) comes into play.

Using some math, we can figure out that for an image that's 500x300, the length between the opposite corners is 583 pixels and some change. So let's set our new inner div to `584px` wide and tall.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">
  <div id="content" style="width: 584px; height: 584px"></div>
</div>
```

Then, let's make sure to center the image inside the inner div, so that when it spins, it always fits.

```
#content {
  position: relative;
}
#content img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

From there, given that the image inside of `#content` is exactly the same size as `#wrapper`, we should theoretically be good to go.

Unfortunately this solution isn't uber flexible as far as supporting arbitrarily sized images or flexible containers. There's not really any `calc()` expression we can use to come up with the size of our inner container (at least that I can come up with) since we're limited in our operations to addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, so you need to calculate that number yourself and use fixed values. But *it does work*, and hopefully being that your use case is a PDF viewer, your images will always be the same dimensions, so you can make it work.

The only hurdle left to clear here is that the image is not totally visible in the container when it's not rotated at all, which is a bit weird. To do that, I'd probably try to set the scroll position of `#wrapper` to match up with the top left corner of the image using JavaScript. I'll leave that to you.

**Demo**

```js
$('#slider').on('input', function(){
  $('#content').css("transform", "rotate(" + $("#slider").val() + "deg)");
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  width: 584px;
  height: 584px;
  position: relative;
}
#content img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="360" step="1" value="0">
```

Comment: Accepted the answer as it fully solves my problem and includes an example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When an html transformation is happening, it works independent of other elements. That means that a transformed element won't move neighbours or resize its parent.

You can use predetermined padding for image's parent. Or you can change it during the transformation but in this case you need to take care of window scroll position.

The needed padding for 90deg rotated element depends on the bigger size of the image you want to rotate and equals:

`(biggerDimension - lesserDimension) / 2`

So, your jQuery function to get the correct padding for parent would be similar this abstract one:

```
var $img       = $('img'),
     imgWidth  = $img.width(),
     imgHeight = $img.height();

if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
  var parentPadding = (imgWidth - imgHeight) / 2;
} else {
  var parentPadding = (imgHeight - imgWidth) / 2;
}
```

If your image is square when no padding is needed (for 90deg rotation).

But if you want to find the maximum needed padding (for 45deg, 135deg etc. rotation) the formula would be a bit more complicated.
For example if the biggest dimension is width and you want to set `padding-top`:

```
sqrt(imgWidth^2 + imgHeight^2) / 2 - imgHeight / 2
```

Half a diagonal minus half a height. You can change the formula for the case when height is bigger and for other corners.

Of course if an img is responsive, you need to call the function on resize.